# uitextfield rightView visible when user typed at least one char in the field

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I was wondering if there is any way I can make the right view of an `UITextField` only be visible when there is at least one character inside, because by setting `UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing` will show it once I focus on the field, not when I start typing.

I could only come up with implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` and doing it on one of the methods that is triggered when the user is typing. The only issue here is that I change the delegate of the text field to something else once I create a text field and add it to the view. That is because I made a custom textfield by subclassing `UITextField` and I init it in various places, and in those various places I assign it's delegate to the current place it's initiated.

Comment: How about, since you already have a custom subclass, giving it a property that's an array of delegates?  The subclass is it's own delegate, and it invokes the delegate selector on everything in the array

Comment: I see ... not sure which way you're going, but how do I then use two delegates in the same time ? Or maybe I should use KVO in the subclass to show and hide rightView and the delegate as I'm already using it ?

Comment: not sure this is appropriate for you, but your subclasses implementation of the delegate method would invoke each member of the array with the delegate messages for (id myDelegate in self.delegates) { /* if it implements selector then */ [myDelegate performSelector:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:); etc.

Comment: I really need an example of that, and it seems a bit inconvenient if I got the idea. Right now, I have my subclass called `RSSUITextField : UITextField`, this does nothing but customises the appearance of the text field. And in various places (`UIViewControllers`) I init the custom text field and I assign the delegate to self `someCustomTextField.delegate = self`, where `self` in this context is the `UIViewController`. Now, how do I use a second delegate inside the custom subclass itself, besides the fact that I need to conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol ?

Comment: I'll tweak my idea a little and write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better idea.  UITextField posts a change notification.  Your subclass can observe itself this way:

```
// in RSSUITextField.m

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(textFieldChanged:)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:self];
```

Then implement `textFieldChanged:` and change your rightView state in there.  This answer is superior to the other I left, but I won't remove that one since that works too, and is a useful technique for cases where the control doesn't post notifications about a state change we care about.

Since each instance of the RSSUITextField will observe itself with the NSNotificationCenter, each is responsible to remove itself as an observer when it no longer matters.  The latest possible time to do this is on dealloc...

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: This what I was think too, but I was a bit unsure if I initiate a dozen of input fields, when navigating away from the view controller, will the observer be removed ? Because at some point if it does not, I will end up with a lot of those. Is there a way of removing the observer once the view controller is deallocated, from the subclass itself ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer works, but there's a better answer for your particular case.  See my other answer... text field posts NSNotification when the text changes....

KVO would be ideal, but the UIKit doesn't promise KVO compliance.  The more abstract problem statement is that you want one object to know something about the text field's state that can only be known by the delegate, but you sometimes want some other object to be the delegate.

The only idea I have that doesn't break any rules is to have the subclass be a proxy for the real delegate, like so...

```
// in RSSUITextField.m
@interface RSSUITextField () <UITextFieldDelegate>
// I will be my own delegate, but I need to respect the real one
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<UITextFieldDelegate>proxyDelegate;

@end
```

In the designated init...

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I am my own delegate, so when the caller of this class wants to get/set the delegate, I need to fool him...

```
- (id<UITextFieldDelegate>)delegate {
    return self.proxyDelegate;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id<UITextFieldDelegate>)delegate {
    self.proxyDelegate = delegate;
}
```

Now the important part (and then sad part).  Important part: we're now in the position to know about our state as a delegate and still respect the caller's idea of the delegate...

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    // show or change my right view

    if ([self.proxyDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:)]) {
        [self.proxyDelegate textFieldDidBeginEditing:textField];
    }
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    // hide or change my right view

    if ([self.proxyDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldDidBeginEditing:)]) {
        [self.proxyDelegate textFieldDidBeginEditing:textField];
    }
}
```

The sad part:  We broke it, so we bought it.  In order to fully respect the delegate, we have to pass on all delegate messages.  This isn't a disaster, because there are only five more of them.  They will all take exactly this form:

```
// I only added this one as an example, but do this with all five others
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if ([self.proxyDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(textFieldShouldReturn:)]) {
        return [self.proxyDelegate textFieldShouldReturn:textField];
    } else {
        return YES;  // the default from the docs
    }
}
```